# How to use FCM instead of GCM with loopback-component-push?

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, loopback

I have an existing loopback application which is about an year old. We were asked to re-implement the app with some different features and marketing. The app has a notification system built using loopback-component-push and is extensively used through the code.

My question is this, can we plug in FCM instead of GCM without disturbing the implementation of all the functionality built on loopback-component-push and associated models? I have searched on the internet and there doesnt seem to be any information relating FCM and loopback

Comment: Have you figured anything out?  I'm trying to send data messages instead of notification messages but it's looking like that's not possible.

Comment: hey.So loopback supported fcm without disturbing any internal implementation so when i plugged fcm ids instead of gcm they worked. If you tell me your exact issue I may be able to help

Comment: Yeah, my issue was that I needed to send a `data` payload and not a `notification` payload.  The loopback-component-push module doesn't support that so basically I forked the library and added the support myself.  Seems like a silly thing to leave out.

Comment: lol yes. But these guys have a lot on their plate especially with typescript support and loopback 4. But glad it worked out :D